# Tab key is not working in firefox at key press event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

TAB Key is not Working in FireFox at key press event for this code

```
   $('.Number').keypress(function (event) {
    if (!/\d/.test(String.fromCharCode(event.which))) {
        $('#error').attr('class', 'errorMessage');
        $('#error').text("Enter Only Numbers");
        return false;
    }
    else {
        $('#error').attr('class', ' display: none;');
        $('#error').text("");
        return true;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('.Number').keydown(function (event) {

    var keycode = event.which;   

    if (!/[\d\t\b]/.test(String.fromCharCode(event.which)) || event.shiftKey ) {
        $('#error').attr('class', 'errorMessage');
        $('#error').text("Enter Only Numbers");
        return false;
    } else {
        $('#error').attr('class', ' display: none;');
        $('#error').text("");
        return true;
    }
});
```

[DEMO](http://fiddle.jshell.net/Pisi2012/2eZR8/)

Comment: ?? I thought you wanted the default TAB-action (jump to next input) for your input field.

Comment: NO FRIEND ITS NOT WORKING. .  yes friend

Comment: What should exactly happen if you press TAB? An error? No error?

Comment: yes friend If i press the tab button it showing error and i need to want back space button also

Comment: Ok, updated my answer. Now your input only accepts numbers, TAB and BACKSPACE. Works in FF and Chrome for me.

Comment: Yes friend is working but the another problem is came some symbols shift pressed are working now (!@#$%^&*()) this symbols are working now

Comment: Yes friend but i need to restricted that symbols also

Comment: Firefox used to fire the keypress event for a tabulator in earlier versions, but now leaves the textarea and does not fire the keypress any more. Therefore, using the keydown event is the correct answer. Thanks!